# Why is an argument with store_false action gives True when the argument is not even used?

Tags: python, argparse

argparse `add_argument` action set to `store_false` gives `True` when the argument is not even used. Why?

**Details**: I'm just trying to understand this example from the official documentation for argparse. On its [discussion of Actions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action), it gives this example:

> `'store_true'` and `'store_false'` - These are special cases of
> `'store_const'` used for storing the values `True` and `False` respectively.
> In addition, they create default values of `False` and `True`
> respectively. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
> >>> parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
> >>> parser.add_argument('--baz', action='store_false')
> >>> parser.parse_args('--foo --bar'.split())
> Namespace(foo=True, bar=False, baz=True)
> ```

Why in the above, is `baz=True`? The final use of `add_argument` uses `action='store_false'`, so I'm baffled as to why calling `parse_args` without even using `--baz` would give that result.

Comment: As the citation you brought states: those actions store the values they name. So if the the argument is not passed, the opposite value is the default. For example, if you have `store_true` it means that if the argument exists, it will have the value `True`. If it is not passed, its default is `False`. The exact opposite holds for `store_false`

Comment: Think about the purpose of the action. Clearly you want to have the opposite default. I'm not sure what your confusion is because you're not describing the alternative behavior you're envisioning. Please explain what you think it should do instead and perhaps I can explain.

Comment: *”`'store_true'` and `'store_false'` [..] create default values of `False` and `True` respectively.”* — Pretty clear and straight forward.

Comment: As for a practical use case, consider: `parser.add_argument('--dry-run', action='store_false', dest='commit')` … `if args.commit: something.save()`

Answer (score 4):

The action 'store_false' sets the argument to false if the argument is given, otherwise, the argument is set to true. That's why when you're not passing the argument in the args, the argument is set to True.